# cassandra 1 big column vs multi small columns in read performance?

Tags: performance, cassandra

I'm getting around 1000 distinct events per second, (4 nodes cluster). After each event I will need to increase some counters. My question is, is it better to have a normal column family which has only one column and all the counters are treated like string with comma "," separated (example: "1,3,5,6,0,2") or it is better to create a Counter Column family with multiple columns? I read some document it says that counter column family can do read and write with consistency level 1 which is fast for reading. I don't really care much about write performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how you are receiving events and latency requirements.

If you are receiving them from multiple sources concurrently and need to write data as soon as possible it would seem that counters would be the better approach. With one big column, you would need to serialize **all** writes to **any** column as well as read the current value. This could also unnecessarily complicate your application code. If performance is a problem, you could try to enable the row cache for your counter column family. I have never tried to cache a counter column family, but I don't see any docs saying it is not supported. You can try it and check the JMX stats to see if it's working.

If you are receiving events single threaded and can do something like read data for 1000 events and then write once to cassandra while keeping the current counter values in memory, then a single column might be fine. But you need to realize that if you happen to just need to read a few counter values at a time, you'll be fetching a lot of unnecessary data on every read. Unless you do some tests that show that one column performs significantly better I would favor counters.